# Coloration in N(0,1) in R

Tags: r, colors, polygon

```
x<-seq(-3,3,0.01)
y<-dnorm(x)
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

It's the code that fill the area -3<=x<=-1 in red

```
polygon(c(x[x<=-1],-1),c(y[x<=-1],y[x==-3]),col="red")
```

I want to fill the area in red between x=0 to x=1, how could i do?
I try a lot, but it still fail. because if i take the interval, it has four vertices, and the N(0,1) distribution is a curve not polygon.

Comment: I use a variation of this function http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/01/11/shading-regions-under-a-curve/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
#your code
x<-seq(-3,3,0.01)
y<-dnorm(x)
plot(x,y,type="l")
#new code
coordx<- c(0,seq(0,1, 0.01),1)
coordy <- c(0,dnorm(seq(0,1, 0.01)),0) 
polygon(coordx,coordy, col="red")
```

Should yield the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could create a vector with the relevant sequence and plot the polygon based on that:

```
xx <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
plot(xx, dnorm(xx), type="l")
polygon(c(min(xx), xx, max(xx)), c(0, dnorm(xx), 0),col="blue")
```